# Is there a method in R to find confidence interval of a proportion by non-parametric percentile bootstrap method

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have a table which has been generated in one of the publication and I am trying to do similar analysis for another study. please help me out to find CI by non-parametric percentile bootstrap method.

here is the table

[image]

I want to know how the ci for 1-RR is calculated.
here is the statistical explanation for it:

We used the Kaplan-Meier estimator18 to construct
cumulative incidence curves and to estimate the risk for
each outcome. The risks were compared via ratios and
differences. We estimated the risk ratio for each outcome
using only matched pairs in which both individuals were
still at risk 7 days after receipt of the third vaccine dose in
those vaccinated. We analysed outcomes in the full
population and in subgroups defined by strata of age,
sex, and number of comorbidities. 95% CIs were
calculated using the nonparametric percentile bootstrap
method with 1000 repetitions. The effectiveness of the
third dose was estimated as 1 – risk ratio. As a sensitivity
analysis, vaccine effectiveness was also estimated as
1 – incidence rate ratio derived from a Poisson regression
using the same dataset, with no further adjustment.
Analyses were done using R software (version 4.0.4)."

How to calculate CI.

Comment: Hello. This site is for specific programming issues. You'll find better advice in https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Be sure your data suitable for this method of CI estimation - you may find this Cross Validated question interesting: [Is it true that the percentile bootstrap should never be used?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/355781/is-it-true-that-the-percentile-bootstrap-should-never-be-used). Also, if you share a sample of your data and provide more details on your analysis you are likely to get faster, better help.

Comment: Look into CRAN package `boot `